# flickr photobar - get description

Tags: photo, flickr

I implemented this jquery http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FlickrPhotobarGallery/ and I can capture setname and title but I need to get description too, so I would like to know if this is possible.

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

```
$(function() {
    var api_key             = '######';
    var user_id             = '####';

    /*
    use:
    Square,Thumbnail,Small,Medium or Original for the large image size you want to load!
    */
    var large_image_size    = 'Medium';
    /*
    the current Set id / the current Photo id
    */
    var photo_set_id,photo_id;
    var current = -1;
    var continueNavigation = false;
    /*
    flickr API Call to get List of Sets
    */
    var sets_service        = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getList' + '&api_key=' + api_key;
    var sets_url            = sets_service + '&user_id=' + user_id + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?';
    /*
    flickr API Call to get List of Photos from a Set
    */
    var photos_service      = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos' + '&api_key=' + api_key;
    /*
    flickr API Call to get List of Sizes of a Photo
    */
    var large_photo_service = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.getSizes' + '&api_key=' + api_key;
    /* 
    elements caching... 
    */
    var $setsContainer      = $('#sets').find('ul');
    var $photosContainer    = $('#images').find('ul');
    var $photopreview       = $('#flickr_photopreview');
    var $flickrOverlay      = $('#flickr_overlay');
    var $loadingStatus      = $('#flickr_toggle').find('.loading_small');

    var ul_width,spacefit,fit;
    add: LoadSets();
    /* start: open Flickr Photostream */
    $('#flickr_toggle').toggle(function(){
        $('#photobar').stop().animate({'bottom':'0px'},200,function(){
            if($setsContainer.is(':empty')){
                /*
                if sets not loaded, load them
                */
                LoadSets();
            }
        });
    },function(){
        /*
        minimize the main bar, and minimize the photos bar.
        next time we maximize, the view will be on the sets
        */
        $('#photobar').stop().animate({'bottom':'-96px'},200,function(){
            $('#images').css('bottom','-125px');
        });
    });

    /*
    Loads the User Photo Sets
    */
    function LoadSets(){
        $loadingStatus.css('visibility','visible');

        $.getJSON(sets_url,function(data){
            if(data.stat != 'fail') {
                var sets_count = data.photosets.photoset.length;
                /*
                adapt ul width based on number of results
                */
                ul_width = sets_count * 105 + 105;
                $setsContainer.css('width',ul_width + 'px');

                for(var i = 0; i < sets_count; ++i){
                    var photoset        = data.photosets.photoset[i];
                    var primary         = photoset.primary;
                    var secret          = photoset.secret;
                    var server          = photoset.server;
                    var farm            = photoset.farm;
                    /*
                    source for the small thumbnail
                    */
                    var photoUrl        = 'http://farm'+farm+'.static.flickr.com/'+server+'/'+primary+'_'+secret+'_s.jpg';
                    var $elem           = $('<li />');
                    var $link           = $('<a class="toLoad" href="#" />');
                    /*
                    save the info of the set in the li element,
                    we will use it later    
                    */
                    $link.data({
                        'primary'   :primary,
                        'secret'    :secret,
                        'server'    :server,
                        'farm'      :farm,
                        'photoUrl'  :photoUrl,
                        'setName'   :photoset.title._content,
                        'id'        :photoset.id
                    });

                    $setsContainer.append($elem.append($link));
                    $link.bind('click',function(e){
                        var $this = $(this);
                        /*
                        save the current Set id in the photo_set_id variable
                        and load the photos of that Set
                        */
                        $('#images').stop().animate({'bottom':'0px'},200);
                        if(photo_set_id!=$this.data('id')){
                            photo_set_id = $this.data('id');
                            $('#setName').html($this.data('setName'));
                            LoadPhotos();
                        }
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
                /*
                now we load the images 
                (the ones in the viewport)
                */
                LoadSetsImages();
            }
        }); 
    }

    /*
    loads the images of the sets that are in the viewport
    */
    function LoadSetsImages(){
        var toLoad          = $('.toLoad:in-viewport').size();
        if(toLoad > 0)
            $loadingStatus.css('visibility','visible');
        var images_loaded   = 0;
        $('.toLoad:in-viewport').each(function(i){
            var $space          = $setsContainer.find('.toLoad:first');
            var $img            = $('<img style="display:none;" />').load(function(){
                ++images_loaded;
                if(images_loaded == toLoad){
                    $loadingStatus.css('visibility','hidden');
                    $setsContainer.find('img').fadeIn();
                }   
            }).error(function(){
                //TODO
                ++images_loaded;
                if(images_loaded == toLoad){
                    $loadingStatus.css('visibility','hidden');
                    $setsContainer.find('img').fadeIn();
                }   
            }).attr('src',$space.data('photoUrl')).attr('alt',$space.data('id'));
            var $set_name       = $('<span />',{'html':$space.data('setName')});
            $space.append($set_name).append($img).removeClass('toLoad');
        });
    }

    /*
    Loads the Set's Photos
    */
    function LoadPhotos(){
        $photosContainer.empty();
        $loadingStatus.css('visibility','visible');
        var photos_url  = photos_service + '&photoset_id=' + photo_set_id + '&media=photos&format=json&jsoncallback=?';

        $.getJSON(photos_url,function(data){
            if(data.stat != 'fail') {
                var photo_count = data.photoset.photo.length;
                /*
                adapt ul width based on number of results
                */
                var photo_count_total = photo_count + $photosContainer.children('li').length;
                ul_width = photo_count_total * 105 + 105;
                $photosContainer.css('width',ul_width + 'px');

                for(var i = 0; i < photo_count; ++i){   
                    var photo           = data.photoset.photo[i];
                    var photoid         = photo.id;

                    var secret          = photo.secret;
                    var server          = photo.server;
                    var farm            = photo.farm;

                    var photoUrl        = 'http://farm'+farm+'.static.flickr.com/'+server+'/'+photoid+'_'+secret+'_s.jpg';

                    var $elem           = $('<li />');
                    var $link           = $('<a class="toLoad" href="#" />');

                    $link.data({
                        'photoid'       :photoid,
                        'secret'        :secret,
                        'server'        :server,
                        'farm'          :farm,
                        'photoUrl'      :photoUrl,
                        'photo_title'   :photo.title
                    });
                    $photosContainer.append($elem.append($link));

                    $link.bind('click',function(e){
                        var $this   = $(this);
                        current     = $this.parent().index();
                        photo_id    = $this.data('photoid');
                        LoadLargePhoto();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
                LoadPhotosImages();
            }

        });
    }

    /*
    loads the images of the set's 
    photos that are in the viewport
    */
    function LoadPhotosImages(){
        var toLoad          = $('.toLoad:in-viewport').size();
        if(toLoad > 0)
            $loadingStatus.css('visibility','visible');
        var images_loaded   = 0;

        $('.toLoad:in-viewport').each(function(i){
            var $space          = $photosContainer.find('.toLoad:first');
            var $img            = $('<img style="display:none;" />').load(function(){
                ++images_loaded;
                if(images_loaded == toLoad){
                    $loadingStatus.css('visibility','hidden');
                    $photosContainer.find('img').fadeIn();
                    /*
                    if we were navigating through the large images set:
                    */
                    if(continueNavigation){
                        continueNavigation  = false;
                        var $thumb          = $photosContainer.find('li:nth-child(' + parseInt(current + 1) + ')').find('img');
                        photo_id            = $thumb.attr('alt');
                        LoadLargePhoto();
                    }
                }   
            }).error(function(){
                //TODO
                ++images_loaded;
                if(images_loaded == toLoad){
                    $loadingStatus.css('visibility','hidden');
                    $photosContainer.find('img').fadeIn();
                    /*
                    if we were navigating through the large images set:
                    */
                    if(continueNavigation){
                        continueNavigation  = false;
                        var $thumb          = $photosContainer.find('li:nth-child(' + parseInt(current + 1) + ')').find('img');
                        photo_id            = $thumb.attr('alt');
                        LoadLargePhoto();
                    }
                }               
            }).attr('src',$space.data('photoUrl'))
              .attr('alt',$space.data('photoid'));

            var $photo_title    = $('<span/>',{'html':$space.data('photo_title')});
            $space.append($photo_title).append($img).removeClass('toLoad');
        });
    }

    /*
    loads the main image
    */
    function LoadLargePhoto(){
        removeLargeImage();

        var $theThumb   = $photosContainer.find('li:nth-child(' + parseInt(current + 1) + ')').find('img');
        var photo_title = $theThumb.parent().data('photo_title');

        var $loading    = $photopreview.find('.loading');
        $loading.show();
        $photopreview.show();
        $flickrOverlay.show();
        $('#preview_close').show();

        var large_photo_url = large_photo_service + '&photo_id=' + photo_id + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?';
        $.getJSON(large_photo_url,function(data){
            if(data.stat != 'fail') {
                var count_sizes         = data.sizes.size.length;
                var largest_photo_src;
                for(var i = 0; i < count_sizes; ++i){
                    if(data.sizes.size[i].label == large_image_size)
                        largest_photo_src   = data.sizes.size[i].source;
                }
                $('<img />').load(function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    /*
                    resize the image to fit in the browser's window
                    */
                    resize($this);

                    $loading.hide();
                    /*just to make sure theres no image:*/
                    removeLargeImage();
                    $photopreview.find('.preview').append($this);
                    $('#large_phototitle').empty().html(photo_title);                       
                }).attr('src',largest_photo_src);
            }
        });
    }

    /*
    close the Large Image View
    */
    $('#preview_close').bind('click',function(){
        $photopreview.hide();
        $flickrOverlay.hide();
        $('#preview_close').hide();
        $('#large_phototitle').empty()
        removeLargeImage();
    });

    /*
    removes the large image from the DOM
    */
    function removeLargeImage(){
        $photopreview.find('img').remove();
    }

    /*
    events to navigate through the Large Images
    */
    $('#preview_img_next').bind('click',function(e){
        /*
        get the next one
        */
        ++current;

        var $link   = $photosContainer.find('li:nth-child(' + parseInt(current + 1) + ')');
        var $thumb  = $link.find('img');

        /* 
        if the next image is not loaded, 
        we need to scroll the photos container 
        and just then continue with the navigation
        */
        if(!$thumb.length && $link.length){
            continueNavigation = true;
            removeLargeImage();
            $photopreview.find('.loading').show();
            $('#images').find('.next').trigger('click');
        }
        else if(!$thumb.length && !$link.length){
            --current;
            return;
        }   
        else{   
            photo_id    = $thumb.attr('alt');
            LoadLargePhoto();
        }   
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#preview_img_prev').bind('click',function(e){
        /*
        get the previous one
        */
        var $link   = $photosContainer.find('li:nth-child(' + parseInt(current) + ')');
        --current;
        var $thumb  = $link.find('img');

        /* 
        if the previous image is not in the viewport, 
        we need to scroll the photos container 
        and just then continue with the navigation
        */
        if(!$thumb.length && !$link.length){
            ++current;
            return;
        }
        if(!$thumb.is(':in-viewport') && $link.length){
            $('#images').find('.prev').trigger('click');
        }                       
        photo_id    = $thumb.attr('alt');
        LoadLargePhoto();   
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    /*
    events to navigate through the sets / photos containers
    */
    var scrollAllow = true;
    $('#sets,#images').find('.next').bind('click',function(e) {
        var target_id = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');

        var $theContainer;
        if(target_id == 'sets')
            $theContainer = $setsContainer;
        else if(target_id == 'images')
            $theContainer = $photosContainer;

        if(scrollAllow){
            scrollAllow     = false;
            spacefit        = $(window).width() -44;
            fit             = Math.floor(spacefit / 105);
            var left        = parseFloat($theContainer.css('left'),10);
            var moveleft    = left - (fit*105);
            if(ul_width - Math.abs(left) < $(window).width()){ 
                scrollAllow = true;
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            $theContainer.animate({'left':moveleft+'px'},1000,function(){
                scrollAllow = true;
                if(target_id == 'sets')
                    LoadSetsImages();
                else if(target_id == 'images')
                    LoadPhotosImages();
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $('#sets,#images').find('.prev').bind('click',function(e) {
        var target_id = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');

        var $theContainer;
        if(target_id == 'sets')
            $theContainer = $setsContainer;
        else if(target_id == 'images')
            $theContainer = $photosContainer;

        if(scrollAllow){
            scrollAllow     = false;
            spacefit        = $(window).width() -44;
            fit             = Math.floor(spacefit / 105);
            var left = parseFloat($theContainer.css('left'),10);
            var moveleft = left + (fit*105);
            if(left >= 0){ 
                scrollAllow = true;
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            $theContainer.animate({'left':moveleft+'px'},1000,function(){
                scrollAllow = true;
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    /*
    when cliking "Back to Sets"
    minimize photos bar
    */
    $('#images_toggle').bind('click',function(){
        $('#images').stop().animate({'bottom':'-125px'},200);
    }); 

    /*
    when resizing the window, resize the main image
    */
    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        var $theLargeImage = $photopreview.find('img');
        if($theLargeImage.length)
            resize($theLargeImage);
    }); 

    /*
    resizes the main image based on the windows sizes
    */      
    function resize($image){
        var widthMargin     = 10
        var heightMargin    = 60;
        var windowH      = $(window).height()-heightMargin;
        var windowW      = $(window).width()-widthMargin;
        $photopreview.find('.preview').css({'width':$(window).width()+'px','height':($(window).height()-25)+'px'});
        var theImage     = new Image();
        theImage.src     = $image.attr("src");
        var imgwidth     = theImage.width;
        var imgheight    = theImage.height;

        if((imgwidth > windowW)||(imgheight > windowH)){
            if(imgwidth > imgheight){
                var newwidth    = windowW;
                var ratio       = imgwidth / windowW;
                var newheight   = imgheight / ratio;
                theImage.height = newheight;
                theImage.width  = newwidth;
                if(newheight>windowH){
                    var newnewheight= windowH;
                    var newratio    = newheight/windowH;
                    var newnewwidth = newwidth/newratio;
                    theImage.width  = newnewwidth;
                    theImage.height = newnewheight;
                }
            }
            else{
                var newheight = windowH;
                var ratio = imgheight / windowH;
                var newwidth = imgwidth / ratio;
                theImage.height = newheight;
                theImage.width= newwidth;
                if(newwidth>windowW){
                    var newnewwidth = windowW;
                    var newratio = newwidth/windowW;
                    var newnewheight =newheight/newratio;
                    theImage.height = newnewheight;
                    theImage.width= newnewwidth;
                }
            }
        }
        $image.css({'width':theImage.width+'px','height':theImage.height+'px'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the description of a set you can call [flickr.photosets.getInfo](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getInfo.html).

On an unrelated note, you can save an API call to flickr.photos.getSizes for each photo in the set by passing in an extras parameter specifying all of the urls you'd like to get back when calling flickr.photosets.getPhotos. For any size identifier (sq, t, m, l, o, etc.), just pass in an extra of url_(identifier) (so, url_o would have the response contain the original url if it was available). This is documented here: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html

Comment: Thanks for answer! I need the description of every photo and I couldn't find the way to adapt this to the plugin :/